# Java - Only read first line of a file

Tags: java

I only want to read the first line of a text file and put that first line in a string array.

This is what I have but its reading the whole file.

ex text in myTextFile:

```
Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10





String line= System.getProperty("line.separator");
String strArray[] = new String[5];


String text = null;
BufferedReader brTest = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myTextFile));
    text = brTest .readLine();
        while (text != line) {
            System.out.println("text = " + text );
             strArray= text.split(",");
         }
```

Comment: Why do you have a loop?

Comment: Also, [here's how you compare strings in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: comparing strings with != does not work too well.

Comment: If you only want to read the first line, why do you have a loop?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I understand you, then

```
String text = brTest.readLine();
// Stop. text is the first line.
System.out.println(text);
String[] strArray = text.split(",");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
```

Answer (score 24):

use `BufferedReader.readLine()`  to get the first line.

```
BufferedReader brTest = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myTextFile));
    text = brTest .readLine();
   System.out.println("Firstline is : " + text);
```

Comment: And add brTest.close() or better use the try (BufferedReader...) { }  construction of Java 8.

Comment: @Anthony, `try (..)` is Java 7 syntax :)

Answer (score 9):

With Java 8 and `java.nio` you can also do the following:

```
String myTextFile = "path/to/your/file.txt";
Path myPath = Paths.get(myTextFile);
String[] strArray = Files.lines(myPath)
    .map(s -> s.split(","))
    .findFirst()
    .get();
```

If [TAsks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24666848/1747457) assumption is correct, you can realize that with an additional

```
.filter(s -> !s.equals(""))
```

Comment: Be careful: Files.lines does not auto close the file.

Comment: will it actually load all content to memory?

Comment: @Yeung, yes, It will load the full file as stream. From the docs:
"Read all lines from a file as a Stream. Bytes from the file are decoded into characters using the UTF-8 charset." If your will work with medium-large files better use bufferedReader solution

Answer (score 4):

Also, beside of all other solutions presented here, you could use `guava` utility class (`Files`), like below:

```
import com.google.common.io.Files;
//...

String firstLine = Files.asCharSource(myTextFile).readFirstLine();
```

Comment: Do you have a link to where the guave utility can be found and how it can be imported?

Comment: Added in answer.

Answer (score 1):

*I think you are trying to get one line only if it's not empty.*

You can use

```
 while ((text=brTest .readLine())!=null){
    if(!text.equals("")){//Ommit Empty lines
         System.out.println("text = " + text );
         strArray= text.split(",");
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
         break;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help someone

to read the first line:

```
public static String getFirstLine() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt")); 

    String line = br.readLine(); 
    br.close();
    return line;
}
```

to read the whole text:

```
public static String getText() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt")); 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    String line = br.readLine(); 

    while (line != null) { 
        sb.append(line).append("\n"); 
        line = br.readLine(); 
    } 
    String fileAsString = sb.toString();
    br.close();
    return fileAsString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
BuffereedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textFile));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
         break;
        }
if(sb.toString.trim().length!=0)
System.out.println("first line"+sb.toString);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the condition of your loop

```
  String[] nextLine;   
  while((nextLine = brTest.readLine()) != null) {
      ...
  }
```

ReadLine reads each line from beginning up to the occurrence of \r andor \n
You can also use [tokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to split the string

```
String[] test = "this is a test".split("\\s");
```

In addition it seems the file is of type CSV if it is please mention that in the question.

Comment: @Unihedron I changed the syntax

Comment: This is a correct, idiomatic approach to read a file, especially when filtering into a `StringBuilder`. Unfortunately it appears not to answer the question.

Comment: @Unihedron whats wrong with it ? it reads all lines one by one, questioner can break the loop after reading the first line.

Comment: Actually, __[empty lines are returned `""` through `.readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())__. Only when the reader has reached end of stream, will `.readLine() != null` return false. Maybe you want `!= null && ! .equals("")`?

Comment: readline stop reading the line as soon as it reaches to a \n or \r, once it reaches to those put whatever it read into nextLine then you can use the nextLine string which contains a line of the file.

Comment: Empty lines in text files are essentially multiple `\n\r`s.

Comment: is it a CSV file ? is this your question?