# How to extract header from input CSV file with OpenCSV?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

[OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) is a java library for reading and writing [CSV files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). I want to read a CSV file and extract the header of the CSV file before handling the data records. How to do this?

This is my current code and where I need the header information:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream()));

CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator('\t').build();

CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(in).withCSVParser(csvParser).build();

// The code that follows depends on the column names, so
// I want to get the header information here so I can
// discover if I have to map to the Book entity class or to another one.

CsvToBean<Book> csvToBeanConverter = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Book>(csvReader).withType(Book.class).build();

Iterator<Book> bookIter = csvToBeanConverter.iterator();

bookIter.forEachRemaining(book -> {
    System.out.println("book: " + book);
});
```

**UPDATE 1**:
I start to think that the two "standard" solutions OpenCSV and apache-commons-csv both have their weaknesses, so feel free to tell me your favorite CSV libraries. Put them into comments, not answers, because it's opinionated information by definition.

**UPDATE 2**:
[How to read CSV headers and get them in to a list in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37519915/how-to-read-csv-headers-and-get-them-in-to-a-list-in-java) is only a workaround-grade solution for this question, because for making it work together with `CsvToBean` it involves `mark()` and `reset()` on the `BufferedReader` and therefor it limits the possible header size, throwing an exception if exceeded. See my answer for for details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read CSV headers and get them in to a list in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37519915/how-to-read-csv-headers-and-get-them-in-to-a-list-in-java)

Comment: @akortex Not really. Only as a workaround, because when you do, then the CsvToBean does not get to know the header and then fails to do the mapping. As a workaround you can mark() and reset() the BufferedReader so that the header information is still available to the CsvToBean class so it can read it again a second time. That feels kind of ugly. I'll nevertheless post the workaround as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use `header = csvReader.readNext()` before creating the `CsvToBean`. However, you have to `mark()` and `reset()` the `BufferedReader` so that the header information can be read again by the `CsvToBean` class in order to do its mapping.
Note that this limits the size of the allowed header to the buffer size of the `BufferedReader` and throws an exception in `reset()` if this size is exceeded.

Here is the code:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream()));

CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator('\t').build();

CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(in).withCSVParser(csvParser).build();

in.mark(8192);
String[] header = csvReader.readNext();
in.reset();
System.out.println("header: " + Arrays.toString(header));

CsvToBean<Book> csvToBeanConverter = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Book>(csvReader).withType(Book.class).build();

Iterator<Book> bookIter = csvToBeanConverter.iterator();

bookIter.forEachRemaining(book -> {
    System.out.println("book: " + book);
});
```